# Return to previous activity on phone back button click With Animation

Tags: android

I have two activities. The first Activity has an imagebutton. on click of this image button, I am launching the 2nd activity with an animation.

**In First activity**

```
ImageButton ibCamera = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibCamera);    
ibCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openTemplateChooser();
        }
    });

private void openTemplateChooser()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), chooseTemplate.class);
    startActivity(i);
    overridePendingTransition( R.anim.anim_slide_in, R.anim.anim_slide_out);
}
```

**The animation XML (Slide IN)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

**The animation XML (Slide OUT)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

The sliding animation works fine and the second activity slides in perfectly. But when I press the back button in my phone, the previous activity comes back without any animation. I want the previous activity to return with the `Slide OUT` animation defined in my XML. How do I achieve that?

**Additional Question**

Is there any way I can override the default transition time during which the animation playes? I want the sliding to happen faster.

Comment: use this backpressed
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in, R.anim.anim_slide_out); orelse overridePendingTransition(0, 0)

Comment: Hi Krisha, where do I write this backpressed code?

Comment: onBackPressed() method in activity